# Confluence: the dropdown beneath the search box

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I am new to Confluence (5.10.7). I am running an instance on my laptop. When I enter any search text in the search box, I am able to see a dropdown, in which there is some content as shown in the following screenshot (I entered "confluence"):

[image]

I would like to know how to remove the dropdown (that is, not displaying the dropdown when search text is entered). I just want to search the entire Confluence (including all spaces). I also hope to know why Confluence shows this dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically that's the suggested pages base on what you are searching and it's not a drop-down menu like other sites. In the other word, it shows the suggested pages base on the keyword. If your result is not listed here you can just enter and it shows all the contents that might be similar to your search keyword. With that said, those suggestions are most similar contents. However, if you want to disable it you might be able to Navigate to **Confluence Admin >> Manage Add-Ons** and disable the **Default section provider for content name search** system plugin.

Please note that it's a system plugin and it may cause a malfunction in search functionality across your instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!